# copy construct from a tensor: USER WARNING

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, torch

I am creating a random tensor from normal distribution and since this tensor is served as the weight in the NN, to add requires_grad attributes, I use torch.tensor() as below:

```
import torch 

input_dim, hidden_dim = 3, 5

norm = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(loc=0, scale=0.01)
W = norm.sample((input_dim, hidden_dim))
W = torch.tensor(W, requires_grad=True)
```

I am getting user warning error as below:

```
    UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, 
    it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or 
sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), 
rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
```

Is there an alternative way to achieve the above? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `W.requires_grad` to `True`

```
import torch 

input_dim, hidden_dim = 3, 5

norm = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(loc=0, scale=0.01)
W = norm.sample((input_dim, hidden_dim))
W.requires_grad = True
```